# error on Gaussian blur with convolution method in openCV2.3

Tags: image-processing, opencv, gaussian

i write use openCV api to create a Gaussian kernel and then pass it to the Conv2ByDFT function to do the convolution. But the program crash and i don't know why. Here is the code.

```
void Conv2ByFFT(const Mat& f,const Mat& g,Mat& result)
{
result.create(abs(f.rows-g.rows+1),abs(f.cols-g.cols+1),f.type());

Size dftSize;
dftSize.width = getOptimalDFTSize(f.cols + g.cols - 1);
dftSize.height = getOptimalDFTSize(f.rows + g.cols -1);

Mat tmpF(dftSize,f.type(),Scalar::all(0));
Mat tmpG(dftSize,g.type(),Scalar::all(0));

dft(tmpF,tmpF,0,f.rows);
dft(tmpG,tmpG,0,g.rows);

mulSpectrums(tmpF,tmpG,tmpF,0);

dft(tmpF,tmpF,DFT_INVERSE+DFT_SCALE,result.rows);

tmpF(Rect(0,0,result.cols,result.rows)).copyTo(result);
}
```

Here is some code in the main() to call the function above

```
Mat gaussianFilter = getGaussianKernel(7,2.0,CV_64F); // create Gaussian kernel
Conv2ByFFT(src,gaussianFilter,result); // do the convolution
```

I don't know if there's something wrong with the getGaussianKernel() function or something wrong with my Conv2ByFFT() function...Can anyone help me? THANKS A LOT!

Comment: What is the error? What line does it crash on?

Comment: sorry i didn't make it clear :P. The error is as follow: "OPENCV ERROR: Assertion failed (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_64FC2) in unknown function,file..\..\..\moduels\core\src\dxt.cpp,line 1483 " and the program crash on the line " dft(tmpF,tmpF,0,f.rows)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your `src` matrix is not in CV_32F or CV_64F (32 or 64 bit floating point) format.  If it is an image, you might need to convert it.

Reminder from OpenCV documentation:

The type of matrix elements is specified in form CV_(S|U|F)C, for example: CV_8UC1 means an 8-bit unsigned single-channel matrix, CV_32SC2 means a 32-bit signed matrix
with two channels.

Here is a complete list of defines from the source:

```
#define     CV_16S   3
#define     CV_16SC(n)   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_16S,(n))
#define     CV_16SC1   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_16S,1)
#define     CV_16SC2   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_16S,2)
#define     CV_16SC3   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_16S,3)
#define     CV_16SC4   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_16S,4)
#define     CV_16U   2
#define     CV_16UC(n)   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_16U,(n))
#define     CV_16UC1   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_16U,1)
#define     CV_16UC2   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_16U,2)
#define     CV_16UC3   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_16U,3)
#define     CV_16UC4   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_16U,4)
#define     CV_32F   5
#define     CV_32FC(n)   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_32F,(n))
#define     CV_32FC1   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_32F,1)
#define     CV_32FC2   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_32F,2)
#define     CV_32FC3   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_32F,3)
#define     CV_32FC4   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_32F,4)
#define     CV_32S   4
#define     CV_32SC(n)   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_32S,(n))
#define     CV_32SC1   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_32S,1)
#define     CV_32SC2   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_32S,2)
#define     CV_32SC3   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_32S,3)
#define     CV_32SC4   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_32S,4)
#define     CV_64F   6
#define     CV_64FC(n)   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_64F,(n))
#define     CV_64FC1   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_64F,1)
#define     CV_64FC2   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_64F,2)
#define     CV_64FC3   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_64F,3)
#define     CV_64FC4   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_64F,4)
#define     CV_8S   1
#define     CV_8SC(n)   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8S,(n))
#define     CV_8SC1   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8S,1)
#define     CV_8SC2   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8S,2)
#define     CV_8SC3   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8S,3)
#define     CV_8SC4   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8S,4)
#define     CV_8U   0
#define     CV_8UC(n)   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U,(n))
#define     CV_8UC1   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U,1)
#define     CV_8UC2   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U,2)
#define     CV_8UC3   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U,3)
#define     CV_8UC4   CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U,4)
```

Comment: yeah you're right!    Mat src = imread("lena.bmp")    so the type of src, as i check is 16. So i use 'convertTo' function to convert it to CV_64F to do the convolution. But after that i need to convert the result back to the original type (here is 16), or the output image seems totally black. I check that type CV_BGRA2BGR565 is 16 so i call ' result.convertTo(newresult,CV_BGRA2BGR565)'. But as i debug the program, i find that the newresult.type() is always 0, not 16. Why does it happen :'(

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to use convertTo since that is for converting color space. You need to convert bit depth, so try cvConvertScale.

Comment: sorry but the first and second arguments of cvConvertScale is IplImage* type, so i call "cvConvertScale(&result,&tmp,1/255)". It crash again and the error says"bad argument". I wonder if there is MAT type can be the argument of this function or must i use IplImage type? (because i use openCV2.3)