# OpenCV calculating square of image Assertion failed error

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, opencv, face-recognition

I'm trying to align a face-image to a reference face-image by using the [Sum of squared Difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) as an error metric [(Image registration)](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/70092/tr-2004-92.pdf). Basically, trying achieve a similar functionality of the cvMatchTemplate function (however I don't have a template image but a common facial expression). When trying to square the difference image, I get an assertion failed error:-215. My question exactly would be: Do I have to use the Matrix multiplication operator A*A or the Per-element multiplication A.mul(A) to get the square of my difference image? (Currently I use A*A)

```
//Start search
Mat result;
for(int i= 0; i<15; i++){
    for(int j= 0; j<15; j++){
        xTrans = i; //Translation on x-Axis
        yTrans = j; //Translation on y-Axis

        //Initialize translation matrix
        double m[2][3] = {{1,0,xTrans}, {0,1,yTrans}};
        Mat map = Mat(2,3,CV_64F, m);

        //Get the transformed image
        warpAffine(displaced, aligned, map, aligned.size());
        //Calculate the sum of squared differences
        absdiff(reference,aligned,result);
        try{
            squared = result*result; //Error line
        } catch (Exception const & e){
            cerr<<"OpenCV exception: "<<e.what()<<std::endl;
        }
        SSD = sum(squared)[0]; //Sum of squared difference
        cout <<xTrans << "," << yTrans << ","<<SSD<<endl;
    }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == B.type() && (type == CV_32FC1 || type ==
CV_64FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC2)) in unknown function, file ..
\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matmul.cpp, line 711
OpenCV exception: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matmul.cpp:711: error: (-
215) type == B.type() && (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_32F
C2 || type == CV_64FC2)
```

Both images have same size and type as warpAffine is working fine. Any suggestions on why this error occurs or the correctness of my implementation would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can only multiply a matrix with itself if it's a square matrix (number of rows = number of columns). What is the size (number of rows & columns) of your matrix "result"?

Comment: result.cols=302 and result.rows=302

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use element-wise multiplication.

```
squared = result.mul(result);
```

Since it looks like you're using floating-point images, you needn't worry about saturation.

Element-wise multiplication multiplies individual elements of two matrices together (hence the name), and requires the matrices have the same size. Each element in your `result` matrix represents the difference of pixel values. Each pixel value is independent of any other pixel values in the image, so element-wise multiplication will produce the proper result.

[Matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) is significantly different from element-wise multiplication. A common application is applying transforms in computer graphics and computer vision. Matrix multiplication is meaningful when applied to the mathematical construct, but not when applied to images. Don't think you must use matrix multiplication, because `cv::Mat` is also used to store image data.

Comment: Could you please explain the difference between the 2 operations? I don't seem to understand it completely.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I'm very new to OpenCV so thanks for explaining it!

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem in this line

```
Mat map = Mat(2,3,CV_64F, m);
```

try this link 
[error on Gaussian blur with convolution method in openCV2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599085/error-on-gaussian-blur-with-convolution-method-in-opencv2-3)